# Does one wife have the right to be treated as good as another

Tags: husband-wife, wife, polygamy

Does one wife have the right to be treated as good as another wife of one husband?

What happens when she is not?
Is there anything she can do? What?

Comment: Polygamy in Islam is based on treating all wives equally and with justice as per Quran. Else the man is asked to marry only one.

Comment: @Ahmed thank you for your reply. i was told what you tell me. my question is: if he has 2 wifes and treats one better is there anything the other can do except to pray? In other words is the equally his responibility to her or it is not to her it is only to G-D?

Comment: It is a command from God to the man. (Quran Surah Nisa Ayah 3). Sister, I'd advise you to involve your elders or close ones to sort out the matter. An online forum isn't exactly the best place to resolve your family issues. May Allah help you and make it easy for all of you. (Surah Link: https://quran.com/4)

Comment: @Ahmed please answer with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, each wife has the right to be treated equally as good the other wife of one husband.

Polygamy in Islam is based on treating all wives equally and with justice as per Quran. Else the man is asked to marry only one.

> O mankind, fear your Lord, who created you from one soul and created
>   from it its mate and dispersed from both of them many men and women.
>   And fear Allah, through whom you ask one another, and the wombs.
>   Indeed Allah is ever, over you, an Observer. And give to the orphans
>   their properties and do not substitute the defective [of your own] for
>   the good [of theirs]. And do not consume their properties into your
>   own. Indeed, that is ever a great sin.And if you fear that you will
>   not deal justly with the orphan girls, then **marry those that please
>   you of [other] women, two or three or four. But if you fear that you
>   will not be just, then [marry only] one or those your right hand
>   possesses.** That is more suitable that you may not incline [to
>   injustice].
>
> [Quran Sura Nisa - 1 to 3](https://quran.com/4)

If she feels that she is not being treated well:
1. She should first speak to her husband and try to sort the matter.
2. If that doesn't work, she should involve her parents/close ones to make the husband understand the issue and sort out any misunderstandings or ill givings from both sides.
3. The last resort is divorce which though Halal is not something beloved to Allah.

As mentioned earlier, an online forum isn't exactly the best place to resolve family issues. I wish you the best and inshallah all will work out for the best in your life.

Comment: You are saying that is he give gifts to one wife more then the other, this is grons for the other wife to try to force her husband for a divore?

Comment: @hazoriz: I'd say you should talk to your husband as to why he gave her more gifts if that's the only concern you have regarding this matter? And inshallah you'll be satisfied with the conversation.